# Can we have a flair-like tooltip for usernames in comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, comments, flair

Sometimes I see comments mentioning edits to questions and I confirm that the poster's reputation is under 2000 before proceeding to make the edit (since I don't want to accidentally clobber his edits if possible). Also sometimes a user will ask a question about SO itself as a comment and in order to answer him properly I need to know what his reputation is so I can tell him what his options are.

I'm wondering if anyone else would see any use for having a tooltip for the usernames in comments. Mouse over a user, and it would pop up at least the reputation number of that user, if not his entire flair box.

It would save me a click every now and then. I might be the only one, though.

---

It would also be useful for Community Wiki questions and answers, as they don't list reputation like normal questions and answers do.

Comment: I can't tell! There's no tooltip and my arthritis is keeping me from clicking your username!

Comment: i cant up vote it cuz i'm new, but i like the idea.

Comment: Well now this is implemented, but it's just a raw number. How long until the Meta questions start coming in "what is this number in the tooltip over usernames in comments??"

Comment: @Kip: Don't say things like that. You make me so sad.

Comment: fyi: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33307/rep-tooltip-doesnt-provide-any-context

Answer (score 1):

Jeff loves jQuery. jQuery tooltip could do this easily. I'd like to see it too.

Comment: The only reason I wouldn't like it is because the tooltip might cover up other comments if you hovered over it accidentally. But, you could always move it :)

Comment: @Chacha102: You'd want to have a short delay on it, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

There's a greasemonkey script to do this...

[Greasemonkey script to load user-rep within comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11036/greasemonkey-script-to-load-user-rep-within-comments)

Comment: Why am I not surprised. ;)

Comment: Oh, I dunno. Hey! You have 1,815 points, and 14 metals :)

Comment: There's a script for that...