# Show full reputation for 10k+ users in tooltip when hovering over rep in sig

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, user-interface

Once a user has over 9999 rep, the rep shown in their signature is truncated (i.e. "10.5k" instead of "10,506").  Would it be possible to show the full rep in the tooltip when hovering over the truncated rep?  Currently there is a tooltip that just says "reputation score".

---

**Update**: I'm putting a bounty on this just to get attention to one of my older feature requests. I suspect this one would be trivial for the team to implement.  Since I'm over 10k rep on meta now, I have some rep to blow on pointless bounties. :)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/can-we-have-a-flair-like-tooltip-for-usernames-in-comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems harmless enough.

This is checked in but will not be deployed until ~9 pm Pacific today.

Comment: cool, thanks. looks like it's already deployed on meta

Answer (score 5):

Why does it matter? And if you're **really** <strike>obsessed</strike> curious, full rep is one click away.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, but it's something they could provide without doing any additional queries (assuming the conversion to "10.5k" or whatever is done on the fly). it's consistent with the way you can hover over user-friendly timestamps to get absolute timestamps.  in my particular case, i wanted to write a greasemonkey script to display rep in hex (just for fun), but i'd like it to be based on the user's actual rep without doing a separate page read.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of showing the Rep when hovering over the truncated Rep, they could just show it in a tooltip when you hover over the user name, just like when you hover over the user name for a comment.

I guess this would also be pretty easy to implement, since it is already done for comment user names.

Comment: that'd be okay too