# Clicking tabs in user profile scrolls to top of page ("tab-top" anchor is missing)

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, design

It looks like a "tab-top" anchor has been removed from the user profile page.  When you are in your profile and click on another tab (say, the "activity" tab), you get a link like `http://stackoverflow.com/users/18511?tab=activity#tab-top`.  However, there is no "tab-top" anchor on this page, so you are taken to the top of the page, rather than to the tabs section.

I *think* this is something that has broken fairly recently.

---

**Bounty**: As a 10k**+** Meta user, I'm putting some of that **+** on the line to draw attention to one of my overlooked posts that should be trivial for the team to address. (Hey, it worked [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29986/show-full-reputation-for-10k-users-in-tooltip-when-hovering-over-rep-in-sig).)

Comment: Actually, the corresponding div id is now "subheader", which now (illegaly) appears twice on the page.

Comment: I dream about putting bounties like you do !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

Comment: that's AWE<strike>FUL</strike>SOME!!  does it auto-update if the question title changes?

Comment: @quack: I take it from the fact that you edited your comment from <strike>SOME</strike>FUL to <strike>FUL</strike>SOME that your opposition to the unicorns is finally gone? ;-)

Comment: awesome to the max!

Comment: @balpha: you didn't see the other edits.  i went thru several flip-flops as to which should be struck.  no, i'm still opposed to unicorns... but this is very creative and silly and seems like an extreme waste of your time.  most excellent.  :)

Comment: well i guess fixing the anchor takes over a week... bounty is awarded for unicornification... :)

Comment: @balpha - I <3 you, mein Freund!

Answer (score 2):

We tested usability when adding the missing anchor, but clicking on tabs was jarring, as some tabs had very differing heights - so we just removed the extraneous local anchor.

This is being pushed to all sites now.

Also, please don't change the accepted answer, as balpha's answer is amazing!