# What's the purpose of setting a bounty to a feature-request?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Team actually pay special attention to Featured questions on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56010/does-the-team-actually-pay-special-attention-to-featured-questions-on-meta)

At the first glance this seems like a try to buy the teams attention... Or is this just to award the best specific implementation suggesting answer for a still-vague feature-request?

Comment: @Gnoupi I ask the bounty-setters for their motivation, not the team for their reaction

Comment: answers on the other question cover your question, in my opinion.

Comment: Coincidentally, Tobias, when I was asking the team for their reaction, my first 4 answers were all bounty setter motivations. I think their answers cover the general scenarios (get feedback from team/community on the feature request, get attention from community for votes, get potential attention from team for action), while there will always be outliers for uncommon reasons (and thus not viable to determine every last motivation).