# Rep tooltip doesn't provide any context

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, usability, tooltips

I noticed that [user rep in tooltips for usernames in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/can-we-have-a-flair-like-tooltip-for-usernames-in-comments) has been implemented. This is great, except that the tooltip doesn't provide any context as to what this number is. It is just a raw number. Maybe the tool tip could say "User's reputation: *n*"?

I know this is very minor; I'm just trying to mention it before "what is this number in the tooltip?" starts appearing on meta every week... :)

Comment: This would be good for the FAQ now that you have noted it :)

Comment: Consistent formatting (comma after thousands) would be good too.

Comment: @Andrew consistent formatting for you, maybe. For me, a dot is used after thousands, not a comma.

Comment: @I hate haikus - so what shows up under Kip's name in his question? 8.881 or 8,881? The important thing is being consistent on the site I guess.

Comment: It shows a comma. I agree, it should be consistent, and it should use a comma, just like everywhere else on the site. I was just pointing out that consistency in formatting is often relative, especially when it comes to numbers and dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the format is now "{0} reputation"