# It's not obvious that a hint shown when I point on a comment author is the author's rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, comments, tooltips

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rep tooltip doesn’t provide any context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33307/rep-tooltip-doesnt-provide-any-context)

Whenever there're comments to any post each comment contains the author name next to it. When I move the mouse to the author name SUDDENLY a hint with a number if shown. Turns out, it is the comment author rep.

This is likely the only place where it is unclear. For example, when rep is shown next to a post it is a number just as well, but the hint clealy says "reputation score [number]".

Why not use "reputation score [number]" or any similar text for comment authors?