# What with the title-text of the links in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a flair-like tooltip for usernames in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/can-we-have-a-flair-like-tooltip-for-usernames-in-comments)

I made a comment below, if you hover over the link to my name, you will see a random number. what the crap does this number mean? It's not my ID... it should say 2119. It doesn't change across comments. So it's like a Comment User ID or something. But what is the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your reputation.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/can-we-have-a-flair-like-tooltip-for-usernames-in-comments) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33307/rep-tooltip-doesnt-provide-any-context)

Comment: Ah ok. yea that explains it. Can close this as a dup. then..